# Override functions for a class instance

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iPhone app and would like to be able to create a similar method to this one from Android's Java:

```
new GetData(this) {

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... string) {
            ((LoginActivity) context).loginCheck(string[0]);
        }
    }.execute(data);
```

Here I override the onProgressUpdate function for each instance to be able to use the result from server in a different way for every instance of my GetData.

In my Objective C code I have the following code:

```
GetData *myGetData = [GetData alloc];
[myGetData initWithValue:@"email=blabla&password=blabla&login=blabla"];
```

How can I override certain functions for my class instance myGetData here?

The ordinary way to override functions in Obj C doesn't seem to work in this case.

I would like to be able to override the didReceiveData:(NSData *) data function in each instance

This is my GetData class now:

```
@implementation GetData
-(id) initWithValue: (NSString*) data{
self = [super init];
// Create the request.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myServer.php"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
// NSString *content = @"uid=273&facebook=1&getUserNotifications=true";
[request setHTTPBody:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[self print];

// Create url connection and fire request
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
return self;
}


- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
// A response has been received, this is where we initialize the instance var you created
// so that we can append data to it in the didReceiveData method
// Furthermore, this method is called each time there is a redirect so reinitializing it
// also serves to clear it
NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
_responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
//NSLog(@"%@", _responseData);
}
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
// Append the new data to the instance variable you declared
NSLog(@"didReceiveData");
[_responseData appendData:data];
NSString *strData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:_responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSLog(@"%@", strData);
}
- (NSCachedURLResponse *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
              willCacheResponse:(NSCachedURLResponse*)cachedResponse {
// Return nil to indicate not necessary to store a cached response for this connection
NSLog(@"connectionwillCacheResponse");
return nil;
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
// The request is complete and data has been received
// You can parse the stuff in your instance variable now
NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
// The request has failed for some reason!
// Check the error var
NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
}
@end
```

Comment: What you use for webservice call ? NSURLConnection ?

Comment: It may not be much difficult for you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/), its networking framework, like [volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) in android.

Comment: In case if you can transfer to AFNetworking I can give you somewhat help with that.

Comment: Unrelated note: don't call +alloc alone like this. +alloc and -init… should always be in the same call. I know you call -init… immediately afterwards, but splitting them this way opens the opportunity for mistakes, and failing to call -init… leads to undefined behavior. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948070/objective-c-two-phase-construction-of-objects (See also the docs for +alloc and +allocWithZone: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/alloc)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this code:

```
typedef void (^data_handler_t) (NSURLConnection*connection, NSData*data);

data_handler_t handler = ^(NSURLConnection*connection, NSData*data){
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
};

handler(nil,[NSData new]);
```

Then define `connection:didReceiveData:` as

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    handler(connection, data);
}
```

pass the block in the constructor:

```
@implementation GetData {
    data_handler_t _handler;
}

-(id) initWithHandler:(data_handler_t) handler {
    _handler = handler;
    // ...
}
```

and call it like

```
GetData *getData = [[GetData alloc] initWithHandler:^(NSURLConnection*connection, NSData*data){
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
}];
```